# Localhost not recognized in windows 7 machine

Tags: iis, port, localhost

I have IIS installed on my windows 7 machine.

But when I try to browse the localhost I am getting 404.

I tried to put netstat and I see

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State 
 TCP    127.0.0.1:80           ABCHOME:49466        TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:80           ABCHOME:49468        TIME_WAIT
```

ABCHOME is the computer name. Any idea how to find what is that foreign address and how can I stop listening to port 80?

I tried uninstall and reinstall the IIS but no luck.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I already have the following entry in host file
127.0.0.1       localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you get a 404 error (rather than no reponse at all) means that you have a webserver running on your computer. Probably not a complete one, but one that at least follows the rules of HTTP.

Skype is a common offender, but there could be others as well.

To see which program is listening, type

```
netstat -nab
```

You have to be running `cmd` with administrative privileges for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you open up command prompt, and type ping localhost do you get a response?

If yes, have you made sure that your new IIS website does not require a host header which you are not using? (Right click the website, Edit Bindings).

Also, make sure that your website is actually running by running the command iisstart.

Finally, are you able to browse to the website in IIS?